# Background Image Responsive Issue

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, background

I am trying to get a responsive background image on my home page only, but it doesn't resize itself when is on mobile screens. 
On laptop it does shrink until roughly 840px width. Then it stops and it seems like zooming in instead.
I did not add the image in the HTML file, is only in CSS and I placed the image in the same folder as css file.
This is what I have done:

CSS:

```
#home {
    background-image: url('london-pic.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 800px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your question is lacking context and we can only "guess" what is wrong. You should provide all the necessary code to reproduce your issue: what is your markup as CSS alone doesn't do anything... This said my guess would be to try removing your min-height property.

Comment: I have tried to remove the min-height property but unfortunately does not fix the issue,

Comment: the website is: www.alessandro-dandrea.com and if you try to minimize you will realize that the image stops at about 850 px width

Answer (score 1):

Using `background-size` will do the trick !

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: It does actually, but then the header with the navigation menu buttons come off from the image when i minimize the screen. They get a white background stripe. any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

In helping you better understand full page background images I think this article explains it really well: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

You can also find there different ways of using this and adapt it to your needs.